# Groupwise uniq command?

Tags: text-processing, awk, group, uniq

I am searching for a command to get from a file in this format:

```
hello 32
hello 67
hi    2
ho    1212
ho    1390
ho    3000
```

To this format (deduplicate by taking the last row of a "group"):

```
hello 67
hi    2
ho    3000
```

At the moment I am using a Python and pandas snippet:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(self.input().path, sep='\t', names=('id', 'val'))

    # how to replace this logic with shell commands?
    surface = df.drop_duplicates(cols=('id'), take_last=True)

    with self.output().open('w') as output:
        surface.to_csv(output, sep='\t', cols=('id', 'val'))
```

---

Update: Thanks for the great answers. Here are some benchmarks:

Input file is 246M and contains 8583313 lines. Order does not matter. First column has a fixed size of 9 chars.

Example of the input file:

```
000000027       20131017023259.0        00
000000027       20131017023259.0        11
000000035       20130827104320.0        01
000000035       20130827104320.0        04
000000043       20120127083412.0        01
...
```

---

```
                              time        space complexity

tac .. | sort -k1,1 -u        27.43682s   O(log(n))
Python/Pandas                 11.76063s   O(n)
awk '{c[$1]=$0;} END{for(...  11.72060s   O(n)
```

Since the first column has a fixed length, `uniq -w` can also be used:

```
tac {input} | uniq -w 9        3.25484s   O(1)
```

Comment: How `tac {input} | uniq -w 9` work?

Comment: @Gnouc, `-w N` will only consider the first `N` chars. For my local file I had a 9 char ID in the first column, so `uniq -w 9`.

Comment: I tested with your input and the result is not correct.

Comment: @Gnouc, Yes for the small input, `uniq -w 5`should work. I think your and Mikels answers are better, since they do not make an assumption about the number of chars in the first column. However, if the input follows such a constraint, then `uniq -w` is the fastest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems crazy, and hopefully there's a better way, but:

```
tac foo | sort -k 1,1 -u
```

`tac` is used to reverse the file, so you get the last rather than the first.

`-k 1,1` says use only the first field for comparison.

`-u` makes it unique.

Comment: ah lol, tac was the solution to my answer haha

Comment: +1, this is the most elegant command line solution that I have seen so far. :)

Comment: This is really good, and it was the first thing I thought of, but couldn't you just `sort -ruk1,1 foo`? Maybe I'm not reading it right, though.

Comment: Thanks, I like that. It's actually a bit slower than Python/Pandas, but clear and concise. And the memory overhead is much better than the Python and other hash-based solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the order of output, here's an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
    {a[$1] = !a[$1] ? $2 : a[$1] < $2 ? $2 : a[$1]}
    END {
        for (i in a) { print i,a[i] }
    }
' file
hi 2
hello 67
ho 3000
```

Answer (score 3):

Some more options:

1. `perl`, if you don't care about the order of the lines.

   ```
   perl -lane '$k{$F[0]}=$F[1]; END{print "$_ $k{$_}" for keys(%k)}' file
   ```
2. A simpler `awk`

   ```
   awk '{c[$1]=$0;} END{for(i in c){print c[i]}}' file
   ```
3. A silly shell one

   ```
   while read a b; do grep -w ^"$a" file | tail -n1 ; done < file | uniq
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it with `sort`

```
sort -u -k1,1 test
```

EDIT: [tac is the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138075/72471)